# Find lines from points

Tags: java, c, algorithm

We have build a laser scanner scanning a room, which works pretty well.
Now we drew our points to a simple JPanel and it looks like this:[image: room]
I connectet the blue points already, but it's not smooth and it doesn't look like a room :)

So is there an algorithm, which draw the lines where are many points and average them, so it looks smooth? Or are there any suggestions, how to develop an algorithm for that?

Our testprogram is written in Java, but later it should be written in Vala(C).

Comment: This isn't so much about programming as it is about algorithms, perhaps [this site](http://math.stackexchange.com/) might be better? Also, the answer to your quesiton is "Yes". We need more information that what you've supplied to give a more specific answer. But again, I recommend the other site for this type of question.

Comment: It could be better. Is it allowed to copy the question and post it there again or what should I do?

Comment: Yes you can do that. I do however recommend to post as many details of how laser scanning works, or at least provide example data and how you'd want it to smooth out.

Comment: yep we need to know which scanning principle you used so we know what errors the data contain like fish-eye, nonlinearity, min/max valid distance, multiple echoes etc ... looks like LIDAR but can be triangulation based or interference instead .... (so the device measure angles or time of travel or interference min/max or combination ...? Also I would add a sketch of the room scanned so we can compare

Comment: Here's the link to the new thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503896/find-lines-from-points